# Min or Max of pandas data series between two rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, max, min, object-slicing

I have a pandas dataframe.  Suppose the column names are 'A', 'B', and 'C'.

How can I calculate the min and/or max of data in column 'A' inclusive of only rows m to p?  Where m < p and m != 0 and p < the number of rows in the dataframe.

What if I store the column names in a list and want to iterate over them in a loop and get the max.

```
colNames = ['A', 'B', 'C']
for col in colNames:
     # get the max here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `.iloc` and `loc`, assuming your m=1 and p=3

```
colNames=['A','B']
df.iloc[1:3,:].loc[:,colNames]
Out[767]: 
   A  B
1  2  2
2  3  1
df.iloc[1:3,:].loc[:,colNames].min() #get the min of each column
Out[768]: 
A    2
B    1
dtype: int64
df.iloc[1:3,:].loc[:,colNames].min(1) # get the min of each row
Out[769]: 
1    2
2    1
dtype: int64
```

Data input

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3],
                   'B':[3,2,1],'C':[2,1,3]})
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
df.A[m:p].min()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!